# Trouble Loading Data for Titanic Visualization

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Having some massive trouble getting my D3 scatter plot visualization running.  Didnt know how to reference the data, so its available from a [dropbox link here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/brvkvzwfk7exbsz/titanic_full.csv?dl=0).

There are a few problems.

1. I am a bit confused about loading my data.

   - I cannot seem to get the data loaded.  I have been successful before, but I am trying to load the data without having to reference a function (i.e., global).  However, as you will see - I am getting nothing - [].
   - Do I need to load it at the bottom of my script and then reference the function within the d3.csv(function(d) {...}, FUNCTION);?  Why cant I simple load it to a variable (as I am trying to) at the top of my script.  Such that its the first object available?
2. I also felt like I had a good handle on the Mike Bostock tutorial about .enter(), update(), .exit().  But I know that I have an issue in the comment section of "//ENTER + UPDATE" where I have circle.circle(function(d) {return d;});.  I dont understand this.

Overall, I am looking to create a scatter plot with fare as my x-axis, age as my y-axis, then loop through the options of "Female Only", "Male Only", "Children Only" and "All" (starting and ending with All).

I plan to add more to this as I get a better understanding of where I am currently stumbling.

```js
   d3.csv("titanic_full.csv", function(d) {
     return {
       fare: +d.fare,
       age: d.age == '' ? NaN : +d.age,
       sibsp: +d.sibsp,
       pclass: +d.pclass,
       sex: d.sex,
       name: d.name,
       survived: d.survived

     };
   }, function(error, d) {
     //Filter out erroneous age values (263 rows are removed)
     var dataset = d.filter(function(d) {
       if (d['age'] >= 0) {
         return d;
       }
     });

     //*Main Elements Setup*

     //Width and height
     var w = 650;
     var h = 650;
     var padding = 20;

     //Create scale functions
     var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
         return d.fare;
       })])
       .range([padding, w - padding * 2]); // introduced this to make sure values are not cut off

     var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
       .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) {
         return d.age;
       })])
       .range([h - padding, padding]);

     var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(xScale)
       .orient("bottom");

     var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .scale(yScale)
       .orient("left");

     //Create SVG element
     var svg = d3.select("body")
       .append("svg")
       .attr("width", w)
       .attr("height", h);

     //Show Axes
     svg.append('g')
       .attr('class', 'x axis')
       .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + (h - padding) + ')')
       .call(xAxis);

     svg.append('g')
       .attr('class', 'y axis')
       .attr('transform', 'translate(' + padding + ',0)')
       .call(yAxis);

     function update(dataset) {
       //DATA JOIN
       //Join new data with old elements, if any.
       var circle = svg.selectAll('circle')
         .data(dataset);

       //UPDATE
       //Update old elements as needed.
       circle.attr('class', 'update');

       //ENTER
       //Create new elements as needed.
       circle.enter().append('circle')
         .attr('class', 'enter')
         .transition()
         .duration(1000)
         .attr("cx", function(d) {
           return xScale(d.fare);
         })
         .attr("cy", function(d) {
           return yScale(d.age);
         })
         .attr("r", 6)
         .attr('fill', function(d) {
           if (d.survived === '0') {
             return 'green';
           } else {
             return 'red';
           }
         })

       //ENTER + UPDATE
       //Appending to the enter selection expands the update selection to include
       //entering elements; so, operations on the update selection after appending to
       //the enter selection will apply to both entering and updating nodes.
       circle.circle(function(d) {
         return d;
       });

       //EXIT
       //Remove old elements as needed.
       circle.exit().remove();
     };

     //The initial display.
     update(dataset);

     //Work through each selection
     var options = ['Female Only', 'Male Only', 'Children Only', 'All']
     var option_idx = 0;
     console.log('next')
     var option_interval = setInterval(function(options) {
       if (options == 'Female Only') {
         var filteredData = dataset.filter(function(d) {
           if (d['sex'] == 'female') {
             return d;
           }
         })
       } else if (options == 'Male Only') {
         var filteredData = dataset.filter(function(d) {
           if (d['sex'] == 'male') {
             return d;
           }
         })
       } else if (options == 'Children Only') {
         var filteredData = dataset.filter(function(d) {
           if (d['age'] <= 13) {
             return d;
           }
         })
       } else if (options == 'All') {
         var filteredData = dataset.filter(function(d) {
           return d;
         })
       };
       console.log('interval')
       option_idx++; // increment by one
       update(filteredData);
       if (option_idx >= options.length) {
         clearInterval(option_interval);
       };
     }, 1500);
   });
```

```css
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: black;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  .axis text {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 8px;
  }
```

```html
<title>Titanic Visualization - Fare and Age Survival</title>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I have an answer, but I probably will not explain this as well.

**1. I am a bit confused about loading my data.**

With the help of @Gilsha, I was able to reconfigure my script to load the data first, with the rest of my script being the 'callback' portion of the d3.csv function.  That worked smoothly.  I also was able to filter my data to remove the blanks right away. Here is that first part:

```
d3.csv("titanic_full.csv", function(d) {
          return {
            fare: +d.fare,
            age: d.age == '' ? NaN : +d.age,
            sibsp: +d.sibsp,
            pclass: +d.pclass,
            sex: d.sex,
            name: d.name,
            survived: d.survived

          };
        }, function(error, d) {
          //Filter out erroneous age values (263 rows are removed)
          var dataset = d.filter(function(d) {
            if (d['age'] >= 0) {
              return d;
            }
          });

            //Rest of script here.
```

**2. I also felt like I had a good handle on the Mike Bostock tutorial about .enter(), update(), .exit(). [Link to Bostock Tutorial I was following](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218) **

Couple things that I did wrong here that was holding me up.  The main item that I was stuck on was this portion:

```
//ENTER + UPDATE
                //Appending to the enter selection expands the update selection to include
                //entering elements; so, operations on the update selection after appending to
                //the enter selection will apply to both entering and updating nodes.
                circle.circle(function(d) {return d;});
```

Basically, I was following the tutorial too closely and didnt realize that when he was using "text.text(function(d) {return d;});", he was setting the **text attribute** (?) to something.  This is where I believe I should be setting any changes to my ENTER and UPDATE selections (all the items that I expect to be in the DOM).  So, when Mike was doing text.text and I replicated with circle.circle, I should have had circle.text(.....).  Or whatever I want there.  Anyone care to comment or explain that better??

PS - I had many other errors... throughout, especially in the section of establishing my interval!

Answer (score 1):

You should write the whole code inside the `d3.csv` callback function. Try this way.

```
d3.csv("titanic_full.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    fare: +d[fare],
    age: d.age == '' ? NaN : +d.age,
    sibsp: +d.sibsp,
    pclass: +d.pclass
  };
}, function(error, dataset) {
  //Filter out erroneous age values (263 rows are removed)
  var dataset = dataset.filter(function(d) {
    if (d['age'] >= 0) {
      return d;
    }
  });
  //Remaining code
});
```

Refer [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parsehttps://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, but thats giving me the error **'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined'**.... Signaling that the dataset is not getting defined.

Comment: Did you check your network tab in browser developer tools? Are you able to see the csv file successfully loaded there?

Comment: Hi Gilsha - this worked!  Now about Question 2 from my original post.  Any thoughts??  I just cant seem to crack the ENTER + UPDATE piece.